# Linq to sql ExecuteQuery for aggregate function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

I am using aggregate function in SQL query and I want the result in linq to sql.

My Query is :

```
 string sql = "Select sum(e.Salary) as 'TotalSalary' from Employee e";
```

and I am using LinqToSql to get the TotalSalary.

```
IEnumarable result = DBContext.ExecuteQuery(sql);
```

How can I get the "TotalSalary" from result?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of `result` at debug time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linq2Sql, you could simply do:

```
var totalSalary = DBContext.Employee.Sum(e => e.Salary)
```

Or, using the custom SQL approach, this is how it could work:

```
string sql = "Select sum(e.Salary) from Employee e";
var totalSalary = DBContext.ExecuteQuery<decimal>(sql).Single();
```

*(adjust `decimal` to your actual data type if needed)*

Comment: I know the first statement. But unfortunately we don't use that. Your second solution works for totalSalary but what if we have "Select sum(e.Salary) as 'TotalSalary', e.DeptId from Employee e group by e.DeptId" ?

Comment: I got the solution. http://geeks.ms/blogs/ohernandez/archive/2008/01/30/executing-arbitrary-queries-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I am new to Linq to sql but I will learn soon. :)

Comment: @UsmanKhalid Great. I still think you should use the power that Linq2SQL gives you instead of writing more code than necessary